# load jquery problem inside loaded file

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have the folowing script; The problem is that i can use the jquery scripts inside the loaded file

index.html

```
<html> 
<head> 
 <title>Ajax with jQuery Example</title> 
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/JavaScript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#wrapper').html(data);
  }
});

  $("A").click(function(){ 
     alert("test inside loaded file");
   }); 

}); 
 </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
 <div id="wrapper"> 
 </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

ajax/test.html

```
<A HREF="document2.html" TABINDEX="4">test alert</A>
```

The problem he will give no alert when i click on the loaded file

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the following line:

```
$("A").click(function(){ 
     alert("test inside loaded file");
   });
```

to

```
$("A").live('click',function(){ 
     alert("test inside loaded file");
   });
```

By using the [Live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method you bind to all `<a>` tags now and in the future, using .click() only binds to the matching elements that currently exist.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach the event to all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future, instead of `click()`.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$("A").live("click", function(){ 
     alert("test inside loaded file");
});
```